# java 8 stream group by two columns

Tags: java-8, java-stream

So I have a class:

```
class AA {
private int number;
private String name; 
private String other; 

public AA(int number, String name, String other) {
    this.number = number;
    this.name = name;
    this.other = other;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getOther() {
    return other;
}

public void setOther(String other) {
    this.other = other;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "AA{" + "number=" + number + ", name=" + name + ", other=" +  
other + '}';
}
}
```

And I creates a list:

```
    List<AA> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new AA(1, "1TEXT", "one"));
    list.add(new AA(2, "1TEXT", "two"));
    list.add(new AA(3, "2TEXT", "three"));
    list.add(new AA(1, "2TEXT", "four"));
    list.add(new AA(1, "2TEXT", "one"));
```

and I would like to group this through columns: number and other to fetch information like below:

```
 * number 1 : - one
              - four
 * number 2 : - two
 * number 3 : - three
```

---

```
Map<Integer,List<AA>> ss = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AA::getNumber));
```

above code will groub pnly through number....
Bu how to group by using two column ?

EDIT: 
I would like to get

```
Map<Integer, List<String>>
```

- where in List we have "other" field

Comment: What do you want to end up with? A `Map<Integer, Map<String, AA>>`?

Comment: thanks I've updated my post :)

Comment: I don't understand - if you get out a `Map` folded only in one dimension, how to you mean "grouped by two columns"?

Comment: one dimension would be integer and secon would be List. Do I have to allways get Map inside Map when I decide to use group by two column ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you're looking for a "second" group by. What you need is just to map the `AA` instances grouped by their `other` property. You can use the downstream collector `mapping` to achieve that.

Looking at the desired output, it seems you need to have a `Set<String>` as values instead of `List`s.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet;

...

Map<Integer, Set<String>> map = 
    list.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(AA::getNumber, mapping(AA::getOther, toSet())));
```